# Can i use invoke on stored tabular function in Log Analytics?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to clean up some shared functionality across queries and would like to have a number of filter functions as stored Log Analytics functions.

Now the below works fine if the function is defined in the same place as the query, but when i split the function into a stored LA function, I can't figure out how to get the invoke operator to work.

```
    `//function to filter 
    let remove_robotstxt=( T:(requestUri_s:string) ) {
        T 
        | where parse_url( requestUri_s).Path != "/robots.txt"
    };
    //
    //
    AzureDiagnostics
    | where Category == "FrontdoorAccessLog"
    | invoke remove_robotstxt()`
```

Passing params such as strings to functions works just fine, but how about tabular functions? What am i missing?

I have tried a union to the function and a number of other things, but my query doesnt seem to see the function being available.

Comment: Same issue for me. It's not available on the pipe. Only at the root of the query, but don't know how to call it in that format.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating the function as a queried table. So in your case:

```
    AzureDiagnostics
    | where parse_url( requestUri_s).Path != "/robots.txt"
```

And save function as AzureDiagnosticsRemovedRobots.

And you can simply call this function directly:

```
AzureDiagnosticsRemovedRobots
| where Category == "FrontdoorAccessLog"
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but it kind of works for me.

Comment: Yes this works and is something we use elsewhere, but i'm not looking to pass between a set chain of functions. What i want is to have filters i can invoke in various queries irrespective of the order or tabular context.